# how to adding this formula in excel sheet

Tags: excel-2007

I want to make formula in excel like below:

If values of column `A` have `abc` then put a number i.e `1` in column `B`, and I am doing like below:

```
IF(A="abc") then (B=1)
```

but its not working.

kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the below formula in column B1.

> =IF(A1="abc",1,0)

The above formula will manipulate the value of cell `A1`
 and if that is `"abc"` then the value of `B1` will become `1` else `0`.

Comment: but I don't to put `0` in other cell, I want to left blank on other cell

Comment: If you dont want to use 0 then try formula =IF(A2="abc",1). But this will return FALSE if the value is not "abc"

Comment: I want like put column `B=1` where `A="abc"`

Comment: @user88 Do you know excel? the given answer is working.

Comment: yes, this answer is working, but not for my condition

Answer (score 0):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="abc",1,"")
```

and copy down.